# Making independent duplicates in SceneKit Scene Graph

Tags: scenekit, particle-system

Creating an SCNParticleSystem by dragging out the icon from the drawer on the bottom right of Xcode, and into the .scn editor creates an SCNParticleSystem.

Editing its values works fine. Get it doing what I want.

Let's call this ParticleSystem_A.

If I then duplicate this particle system, and rename it to ParticleSystem_B, and change any of its values, all corresponding values in ParticleSystem_A also change, in exactly the same manner.

No matter where I re-order, rename or otherwise manipulate these two particle systems within the editor, changing the values of one always changes the value of the other. It seems impossible to "unlink" them.

Is there a way, in the editor, to unlink them?

Comment: When I drag the SceneKit Particle System File thing from the bottom right drawer, it doesn't create a new particle system in the Scene graph editor. How are you able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to unshare this in Xcode7 (please file a request). You will have to drag a new particle system instance from the object library to get an independent particle system.

Comment: How do I file a request?

Comment: This is actually a serious question. I hear "file a radar", "file a bug report" "file a feature request", "opened a bug report" etc... everywhere. And they all seem to point to the same thing, Apple's bug report "platform": https://bugreport.apple.com .... has anyone looked at the login page for this... it looks like a phishing site. But I'm only getting started. Where do I file a feature request? Xcode, iOS, iOS SDKs? And why should I, if they don't respond to bug reports on their bug reports service? Is it like Adobe, just a way to hide issues and missing features from google's searching?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to duplicate sprite kit particle emitters as follows. I imagine that the same technique would work for scene kit emitters.

First, duplicate the .sks file (or .scnp file for Scene Kit particle emitters) which represents the particle emitter in the Finder. Then, import the new copy into your project. You will now have two identical particle emitters but can change the values independently.

Comment: Good hack! I'll try it. Won't be much fun with dozens of systems, which is what I'm playing with, but it's a step in the right direction. @toyos, you still thinking about adding independent duplicates to SCN and SK?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way.

1 Duplicate particle system as much as you need.
2 Rename duplicated ones.
3 Drag duplicated particle systems to an other Scene.
4 Delete original ones.
5 Drag back the particle systems back to Scene you want them to be.

Now they are separated.